# How can I make sure that my OS works without any screen?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

So I downloaded the OS on the SD card and I want to make sure that the system works? I just started my raspberry adventure, and I'm completely new to this.

I also tried to connect my Raspberry by Network cable to my computer but at VNC It says that it can't show the image.

Comment: First of all, have you completed the installation of Raspbian or do you want to install it without any interaction?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community @Eilios. Add the procedure that you do to enable VNC on your raspberry pi. Also, it would be helpful if you add the exact model of the device and the operating system you have flashed to the sd-card.

Comment: Because you are completely new to Raspberry Pi there is a very good site to start with. Please have a look https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/. There you will also find hints how to use your RasPi headless, means without monitor and keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can enable ssh by creating a file named `ssh` without any extension on your SD card and rebooting your Pi. Then you can connect to your Pi through ssh from another machine by using `ssh pi@yourPiName.local` (*where yourPiName is raspberry or whatever you set*) or `ssh pi@yourPiIpAddress` )*where yourPiIpAddress is the IP address of your Pi*) and using `sudo raspi-config` to change settings to enable VNC.

Secondly, [according to here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216737):

> The RPi must be set to boot to desktop (service mode).
>   If a HDMI monitor is not attached then you need to specify a screen resolution in config.txt
>   Use GUI config tool or sudo raspi-config to do that.
>
> If not booting to desktop then you need to use virtual mode. (Run vncserver from the command line).

You can set the resolution from `ssh` :

1. by using the `sudo raspi-config` command and then selecting `7 Advanced Operations` followed by `5 Resolution`
2. by using the `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` (*or another text editor, I prefer nano*) and uncommenting several lines and setting the mode like below (*hdmi_mode=16 is 1024x768*):

```
# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=16
```

More info here: [Troubleshooting VNC Server / Changing the Raspberry Pi’s screen resolution](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002249917-VNC-Connect-and-Raspberry-Pi#troubleshooting-vnc-server-0-7)

If you continue to get the error still then try:

> After changing the resolution to the highest it was solved (sudo raspi-config)

Comment: Yeah, I did it but on VNC it says "Cannot currently show the desktop" and I'm ain't sure if the OS works properly and I want to check it somehow.

Comment: If you can connect through ssh as I mentioned above then the OS works properly.

Answer (score 2):

To verify that the OS works, in the boot section of the micro SD card, create a file named "ssh" without an extension. Then, connect an Ethernet cable to the Raspberry Pi and connect the other end to your router. Boot up your Pi by powering it up.

Next, get an IP scan application (I used Angry IP Scanner) and locate the IP address of your Pi. It will be listed under "raspberrypi.local". Install an SSH client and connect it with the IP address you got with the scanner. You'll be asked to enter the username and password. By default, the username is "pi" and the password is "raspberry". If your Linux bash shell opens up, you're good to go.

Alternatively, you can use the *ping* command on your shell in this format: 

`ping [yourIP]` where "yourIP" is the Pi's IP address. If it says it's receiving pings, the Pi is working.